# How to avoid factory reset and bypass unlock pin on my kyrocera 2.2 froyo

Tags: lock-screens

I forgot my unlock pin but i dont want to hard reset my kyrocera M9300 HOW CAN I BYPASS

Comment: Can you not use your Gmail account to sign in?

Comment: If you have any custom recovery or open download/fastboot mode, you can flash password reset zip.

Answer (score 0):

Flash a stock firmware with fastboot. Look for instructions on XDA. It's not nearly as hard as it sounds.

Comment: How will flashing the firmware help? The unlock PIN is not stored in the system partition.